# What OpenType typographic features does Qt support?

Tags: qt, opentype

I'm curious whether Qt supports features like alternate figures (tabular or old style).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: None.

Qt uses FreeType to render the fonts. While the FreeType library itself provides an OpenType extension, the `QFont` object in Qt does not provide any API for Open Type extensions.

- See for FreeType: http://freetype.org/opentype/index.html
- Set Qt Doc for `QFont`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QFont.html